# calling server side event from html button control

Tags: asp.net, html

I am creating an application using ASP.Net, in which I have a HTML button on an aspx page.

```
<input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" runat="server" 
   style="background-image:url(App_Themes/default/Images/quiz_class/btn_submit.jpg);
   width:80px; height:29px;" onserverclick="btnSubmit_ServerClick" />
```

But when I click on the button then it not calling the btnSubmit_ServerClick event on the aspx.cs page.

I don't want to use asp control button.

Please help..

Comment: Sooo...  It's been 3 years.  Did you ever get this figured out?  Accept an answer!  (Even if you have to create it first)

Answer (score 44):

If you are OK with converting the input button to a server side control by specifying `runat="server"`, and you are using `asp.net`, an option could be using the [HtmlButton.OnServerClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlbutton.onserverclick(v=vs.80).aspx) property.

```
<input id="foo "runat="server" type="button" onserverclick="foo_OnClick" />
```

This should work and call `foo_OnClick` in your server side code.
Also notice that based on Microsoft documentation linked above, you should also be able to use the HTML 4.0  tag.

Comment: How do you declare `foo_OnClick`?

Comment: Got it: `<script language="C#" runat="server">` `</script>`  Your C# stuff has to be in here.

Answer (score 5):

On your aspx page define the HTML Button element with the usual suspects: runat, class, title, etc.

If this element is part of a data bound control (i.e.: grid view, etc.) you may want to use CommandName and possibly CommandArgument as attributes.  Add your button's content and closing tag.

```
<button id="cmdAction" 
    runat="server" onserverclick="cmdAction_Click()" 
    class="Button Styles" 
    title="Does something on the server" 
    <!-- for databound controls -->
    CommandName="cmdname"> 
    CommandArgument="args..."
    >
    <!-- content -->
    <span class="ui-icon ..."></span>
    <span class="push">Click Me</span>
</button>
```

On the code behind page the element would call the handler that would be defined as the element's ID_Click event function.

```
protected void cmdAction_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
: do something.
}
```

There are other solutions as in using custom controls, etc. Also
 note that I am using this live on projects in VS2K8.

Hoping this helps.
Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to override the RaisePostBackEvent method.

```
<input type="button" ID="btnRaisePostBack" runat="server" onclick="raisePostBack();" ... />
```

And in your JavaScript:

```
raisePostBack = function(){
    __doPostBack("<%=btnRaisePostBack.ClientID%>", "");
}
```

And in your code:

```
protected override void RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler source, string eventArgument)
{
    //call the RaisePostBack event 
    base.RaisePostBackEvent(source, eventArgument);

    if (source == btnRaisePostBack)
    {
         //do some logic
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried this code, a postback is triggered but `protected override void RaisePostBackEvent`  function is not executed. how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this tutorial: http://decoding.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/aspnet-how-to-call-a-server-side-method-from-client-side-javascript/

On a sidenote: ASP.NET generates a client side javascript function that you can call from your own functions to perform the postback you want.

-- More info on hijacking the postback event:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720099(vs.71).aspx
- http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1082/dopostback-function/
- http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2005/11/04/59081.aspx

Answer (score 0):

just use this at the end of your button click event

```
protected void btnAddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ... save data routin 
     Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use event handler serverclick as below

//cmdAction is the id of HTML button as below

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <button type="submit" id="cmdAction" text="Button1" runat="server">
            Button1
        </button>
    </form>
</body>
```

//cs code

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                cmdAction.ServerClick += new EventHandler(submit_click);  
        }

        protected void submit_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Write("HTML Server Button Control");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For people trying dealing with a checkbox, exactly none of these solutions work since you'd need it to be an HTML input (and not an HTML button).

SPArcheon's answer doesn't work as soon as you add `type="checkbox"` which is needed for the `.checked` operator to work in the code-behind. As soon as you add `type="checkbox"`, there is no `OnServerClick`, `ServerClick`, nor `CheckedChanged` for an HTML Input box. All you have is `ServerChanged`, which is useless because it requires a full page refresh.

I actually had to use CSS to make an HTML button resemble a checkbox using Bootstrap's btn-outline-secondary class as a starting point.

```
.btn-checkbox-unchecked {
    padding: .35rem .35rem !important;
    font-size: .875rem !important;
    line-height: .5 !important;
    border-radius: .15rem !important;
    border-width: .20em !important;
}

.btn-checkbox-checked {
    padding: .1rem .1rem !important;
    font-size: .6rem !important;
    line-height: .5 !important;
    border-radius: .15rem !important;
    border-width: .20em !important;
    border-color: #0060df !important;
    background-color: #0060df !important;
}

    .btn-checkbox:hover {
        border-color: #676774 !important;
        background-color: #0250BB !important;
    }
```

In the aspx:

```
<button class="btn btn-xs btn-outline-secondary" id="btnFakeCheckbox" runat="server" clientidmode="static" autopostback="true" data-bs-toggle="button" autocomplete="off"></button>
```

Then in your code-behind, you can set attributes (classes) accordingly

For when it's checked:

```
btnFakeCheckbox.Attributes.Add("class", "btn btn-xs btn-secondary btn-checkbox-checked active")
btnFakeCheckbox.Attributes("aria-pressed") = "true"
btnFakeCheckbox.InnerHtml = "<i class='fas fa-check'></i>"
```

When it's unchecked:

```
btnFakeCheckbox.Attributes.Add("class", "btn btn-xs btn-outline-secondary btn-checkbox-unchecked")
btnFakeCheckbox.Attributes("aria-pressed") = "false"
btnFakeCheckbox.InnerHtml = ""
```

(Note the font awesome check icon on the last line, you'll have to include that in your aspx)

What an absolutely absurd workaround for an even more absurd framework. If anyone has a solution for a Bootstrap 5 toggle switch, let me know.