# if(btnaAddStudent_Click) pop-out notif will be shown and redirect to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net

After tapping the add student button... I want to show a pop-out notification that it successfully add a student and redirects to `Attendance.aspx`. How would I do that?

**MY Code**

```
~~~if(btnaAddStudent_Click)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Adding Student Successful')</script>");
        Response.Redirect("~/Attendance.aspx");
    }~~~
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# code behind for Button Click Event, ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44547143/c-sharp-code-behind-for-button-click-event-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach:

First create Javascript function like:

```
<script>
    function showMessageAndRedirectToAttandancePage() {
        alert("Adding Student Successful");
        window.location.href = "/Attendance.aspx";
    }
</script>
```

Then you should call this function from code behind:

```
if(btnaAddStudent_Click)
{
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "showMessageAndRedirectToAttandancePage()", true);
}
```

Comment: How do I add a JavaScript function @selim-yıldız sir? I'm new to these. Can you show me where to can I add JavaScript function to implement your answer?

Comment: Implementing your answer shows:


~~~<script>
    function showMessageAndRedirectToAttandancePage() {
        alert("Adding Student Successful");
        window.location.href = "/Attendance.aspx";
    }
</script>~~~  //error occurs in this line..

Comment: Add to your aspx page