# i am trying to run a asp.net method with an html submit button but method would not run?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I want the method submit_click to be activated when the submit button on the HTML part is pressed

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" Debug="true" %>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post" onsubmit="Submit_Click">
            mail<br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="mail" runat="server" Style="margin-left: 0px">mail</asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            name<br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server" Width="117px">name</asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            last
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="last" runat="server">name</asp:TextBox>

            <p>
                pass

                </p>
            <p>

                <asp:TextBox ID="password" runat="server">password</asp:TextBox>
                </p>


           id <p>
                <asp:TextBox ID="id1" runat="server">id</asp:TextBox>
            </p>
            <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="submit" onserverclick="Submit_Click()" />

        </form>


    </body>
    </html>
```

```
        using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data.OleDb;
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



        }
        protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data source = " + Server.MapPath("") + "\\Database.accdb");
                conn.Open();
                string com = "INSERT into myusers (myid,myname,mymail,mypass,mylast) VALUES ('" + id1.Text + "," +name.Text + "," + mail.Text  + "," +password.Text + "," + last.Text + "')";
                OleDbCommand comm = new OleDbCommand(com, conn);
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();


        }


    }
```

Comment: try "Submit_Click()" in cshtml

Comment: Please be sure to parameterize your insert statement. What happens when someone enters their last name as `'); DROP TABLE myusers;--`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12474110/4827273 this might help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually why you're doing this , that i don't know because **Asp Button will also converted like below on browser side**, Still if you want to use it put **runat="server"**, try below code.

```
<input id="Submit" runat="server" type="submit" value="submit" onserverclick="Submit_ServerClick" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing 'runat="server"'. Include it in the submit control.